# Convert string date to MySQL datetime

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a series of dates stored in my database from an import. They're in the format of

> Tue 2 Sep 2014

What would be the best way to convert this to MySQL date format, for example, yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss either using PHP or MySQL.

Thanks

Comment: Perfect thank you, I didn't see that one whilst searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, just use `date()` combined with `strtotime()`

```
$date = "Tue 2 Sep 2014";
$conv = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
echo $conv;
```

output:

```
2014-09-02 00:00:00
```

To omit the time just remove `H:i:s`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_to_date` function to convert a string to a date as

```
mysql> select str_to_date('Tue 2 Sep 2014','%a %e %b %Y') as date ;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2014-09-02 |
+------------+
```

You can also format the date as

```
mysql> select date_format(str_to_date('Tue 2 Sep 2014','%a %e %b %Y'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as date ;
+---------------------+
| date                |
+---------------------+
| 2014-09-02 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Check more about date_format and other date functions here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format